# Video file upload in mvc 3 using ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, video, upload

Hi I tried to save image path in my database and retrieve it to my view to display image using the code below. Which is running perfectly. My problem now is how can I save video file using ajax? I used ajax because I'm not only saving images but I also have different data to save. e.g Name,code,blurb,synopsis etc. Thank you in advance for helping me.

In my view:

```
<tr>
                <td>
                    Poster Homepage
                </td>
                <td style>
                    <form id="file_upload" action="/Movies/UploadFiles" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="fileupload-buttonbar">
                        @*<div class="progressbar fileupload-progressbar">
                        </div>*@
                        <div id="file_name">
                        </div>
                        <div id="file_type">
                        </div>
                        <div id="file_size">
                        </div>
                        <div id="show_image"></div>
                        <span class="fileinput-button"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="upload-image">
                            Upload image</a>
                            <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple id="file" />
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.progressbar').progressbar({ value: 0 });

        $('#file_upload').fileupload({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/Movies/UploadFiles',
            progressall: function (e, data) {
                $(this).find('.progressbar').progressbar({ value: parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10) });
            },
            done: function (e, data) {
                $('#file_name').html(data.result.name);
                $('#file_type').html(data.result.type);
                $('#file_size').html(data.result.size);
                $('#show_image').html('<img src="/home/image/' + data.result.name + '" />');
                $('#file_name').css({ display: 'none' });
                $('#file_type').css({ display: 'none' });
                $('#file_size').css({ display: 'none' });
                //visibility: hidden;
                $(this).find('.progressbar').progressbar({ value: 100 });
            }
        });
```

Controller:

```
public FilePathResult Image()
        {
            string filename = Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Replace("/home/image", "");
            string contentType = "";
            var filePath = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Images") + filename);

            var index = filename.LastIndexOf(".") + 1;
            var extension = filename.Substring(index).ToUpperInvariant();

            // Fix for IE not handling jpg image types
            contentType = string.Compare(extension, "JPG") == 0 ? "image/jpeg" : string.Format("image/{0}", extension);

            return File(filePath.FullName, contentType);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ContentResult UploadFiles()
        {
            var r = new List<UploadHomePage>();

            foreach (string file in Request.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase image = Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFileBase;
                if (image.ContentLength == 0)
                    continue;
                string savedFileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images"), Path.GetFileName(image.FileName));
                image.SaveAs(savedFileName);

                r.Add(new UploadHomePage()
                {
                    Name = image.FileName,
                    Length = image.ContentLength,
                    Type = image.ContentType
                });
            }

            return Content("{\"name\":\"" + r[0].Name + "\",\"type\":\"" + r[0].Type + "\",\"size\":\"" + string.Format("{0} bytes", r[0].Length) + "\"}", "application/json");
        }
```

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace BookingCMS.Models
{
    public class UploadHomePage
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Length { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass additional parameters with the FileUpload plugin using the `formData` setting:

```
$('#file_upload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/Movies/UploadFiles',
    formData : { 
        name: 'this is the name of the movie', 
        synopsis: 'this is the synopsis of the movie',
        type: 'movie'
    },
    progressall: function (e, data) {
        ...
    },
    done: function (e, data) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering I didn't know that but what I want is after selecting what the movie trailer..The user will click the Add button and all the user inputted data will save in the database..all I need to do is upload video file in my directory and view it in my view just like what the above code does..the only different is,this is video and the above code is saving images..Thanks for helping.

Comment: You cannot use AJAX to upload files to the server.