# Displaying Medias on Asp.Net Mvc Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

I want to upload video and I want to show this video on my page. Media or Video must be showed on page after it uploaded.

Program should support all video formats and work on all platforms (mobile platforms and browsers)

I am working with Telerik Asp.Net Mvc Extensions.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: My question seems fairly clear.

Comment: There is no question mark even.please tell what you have done and what you are expecting clearly.Then only anyone can able to help.

Comment: Your question doesn't provide any code.

Comment: And it is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918146/simple-video-uploading-and-playing-app-using-telerik-asp-net-mvc. Please don't do that.

Comment: I couldn't get any answer my previous question. I just want to upload a video and I want this video to play screen without needing download. Is it more clear guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First divide your process as two tasks.

1. first upload video file into application,Save it in folder or database [File Upload in Asp.net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15355050/video-file-upload-in-mvc-3-using-ajax)
2. Then load it in your mvc web page for display [Display Video file on page](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=998)

Comment: Thanks for help and sorry to ask duplicate question bro.

Comment: better to delete duplicate post.That might help to Stackoverflow site